# Keras custom loss not calculated correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to use a custom loss function in Keras. My implementation looks something like:

```
class LossFunction:
    ...

    def loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        ...
        localization_loss = self._localization_loss()
        confidence_loss = self._object_confidence_loss()
        category_loss = self._category_loss()

        self.loc_loss = localization_loss
        self.obj_conf_loss = confidence_loss
        self.category_loss = category_loss

        tot_loss = localization_loss + confidence_loss + category_loss
        self.tot_loss = tot_loss
        return tot_loss
```

I then define custom metrics to look at the stored tensors like:

```
class MetricContainer:
    def __init__(self, loss_obj):
        self.loss = loss_obj

    def local_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return self.loss.loc_loss

    def confidence_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return self.loss.obj_conf_loss

    def category_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return self.loss.category_loss

    def tot_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return self.loss.tot_loss
```

I then compile my model with this command:

```
model.compile('adam', 
              loss=loss_obj.loss,
              metrics=[metric_container.local_loss, 
                       metric_container.confidence_loss, 
                       metric_container.category_loss, 
                       metric_container.tot_loss])
```

When I train the model (on a very small training set) I get output like:

```
Epoch 1/2
1/2 [==============>...............] - ETA: 76s - loss: 482.6910 - category_loss: 28.1100 - confidence_loss: 439.9192 - local_loss: 13.1180 - tot_loss: 481.1472 
2/2 [==============================] - 96s - loss: 324.6292 - category_loss: 18.1967 - confidence_loss: 296.0593 - local_loss: 8.8204 - tot_loss: 323.0764 - val_loss: 408.1170 - val_category_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_confidence_loss: 400.0000 - val_local_loss: 6.5036 - val_tot_loss: 406.5036
```

For some reason `tot_loss` and `loss` don't match, even though I should be using the same value for them.

Any idea why this might be happening? Does Keras do something to modify the loss after you return it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loss is equal to a sum of a chosen loss function and regularization terms. So if you use any kind of regularization - it's affecting your loss by adding regularization terms.

Comment: Looks like that was it. I loaded a predefined model and didn't realize its layers had regularization loss attached.